# Is it possible to have Peace Walker like button mapping in MGS1, 2, 3? Or how to have efficient gameplay?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-hd-collection, metal-gear-solid-peace-walker, metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, metal-gear-solid-series

I ve bought MGS HD Collection, since MGS1 wasn t part of the pack, I started with Peace Walker (thinking it was a spin off, shame on me, it s between 4 and 5).

Now, I m starting MGS3: Snake Eater, and I really struggle with the command, which are the same for MGS1 and MGS2.

In MGS:PW, L1 is aim, R1 is fire, hold square or press R2to change weapon, hold triangle or L2 for changing items.

In other MGS, it feel like all other the place, R1 is for first peron (and so aiming), square is fire when you unhold the button after pressing it.

Why do I have to use square, and so move my thumb from the analog stick, if I want to fire? Furthermore, it prevent me from walking and so avoid enemy fire, or adjust my position if the target move out of my filed of vision.

I m still on the first mission of MGS3 after 2hours of playing, I feel like a MGS:PW button mapping would have taken me to the second mission easily for the same amount of time.

All I saw in option (for MGS3) is Classic or 3rd person View (which is exclusive to MGS3HD), and no "Button mapping" option whatsoever.

How am I supposed to play to take advantage of using square to fire and R1 for 1rst person view?

EDIT: Expanded the question to MGS1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MGS:PW had drastically different controls in the HD bundle due to a combination of it originating on the PSP which lacked the L2/R2 buttons and Kojima experimenting with alternate control styles.
I believe that the original version of this game allowed for a variety of control schemes.

New control schemes were not added to other MGS games as this would have have essentially changed the games' play styles, making them more than just a HD remake.

You may note that MGS3 has different controls to the original version that was released (for example the new orbital camera).
This is because the version in the HD bundle is a slimmed down, HD remake of MGS3: Subsistence (a later release of MGS3 with extra content but missing some content such as the "Snake vs Monkey" mini game and the "Nightmare" mini game/dialogue).
The new control scheme was introduced in the Subsistence version, not the HD remake.

So in short: no, you cannot change the control schemes beyond the options in the source games because this would make them more than a "HD remakes".

Comment: That s sad for me, but confirm what I thought.

Comment: All I can say is play them in order of creation, not chronologically.
This will take a bit of the difficulty out of switching to the older control layout later down the track.

Comment: Problem is, I already begun by PW, and loved the control. I will try to go to MGS3 (except the fact I can t walk crouched and 1st person view when aiming, it s almost the same command as PW)